# How to have input/search bar eventlisteners not fire off so much

Tags: javascript

I have a search bar at the top of my page where I want to have the user look for a specific query and then the page will hide all blog posts that do not contain that query. However, I have an issue where I have an eventListener listening for input within my search bar but when I console.log out a value in one of my callback functions in the eventListener, it fires off a LOT. I believe this is an issue that is affecting a crucial part of my website so I hope to fix it soon.

Here is my initialization code for the client-side javascript:

```
function init() {
    makeCardRequest();
    let input = qs('#search-term');
    input.addEventListener('input', updateSearchButton);
    let home = qs('#home-btn');
    home.addEventListener('click', goHome);
  }
```

Here is the chain of callback functions for the input:

```
  function updateSearchButton() {
    let button = qs('#search-btn');
    if (this.value.trim() !== '') {
      button.disabled = false;
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        search(this.value);
      });
    } else {
      button.disabled = true;
    }
  }

  async function search(query) {
    qs('#search-btn').disabled = true;
    let cards = qsa('article');
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      cards[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    console.log(cards);
    let home = qs('#home');
    home.classList.remove('hidden');
    fetch('yipper/yips?search=' + query)
      .then(statusCheck)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(processData)
      .catch(console.error);
  }
```

Where I notice the issue is that when I log out cards in my search function, it logs it out into the console for each character I put in the search bar. For example, if I search 'Hello', it will log the cards out 5 times.

Comment: Use `change` instead of `input` if you want to get notified only when the user changed something and then removed focus of the field instead of getting notified at every input. Or use a debouncer.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way where I could use 'change' and still have it where all I have to do is type something without clicking out of the search bar to make the search button not be disabled?

Comment: Do you want that users that come to your site just come and when they press letters on keyboard it opens the search bar automatically without the need to click on search bar, like you can find at search engine websites?

Comment: I can see that you have an event listener for a `#search-btn` with a callback, calling the actual `search()`. So, is the idea that the search only happens when the user hits the button or should the search also happen while the user is typing?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You want instant feedback, yet you don't want to get instant events when something changed...?